# Firestore Cloud Function - CORS error with amazon scraper / puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cors, puppeteer

i have to following cloud function to scrap amazon with puppeteer and i always got an CORS error back, when i call this function with my ionic app.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

admin.initializeApp();

export const scrapeAmazonNew = functions
.runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 120,
    memory: '1GB',
  })
.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
      const { url } = req.body;
      const db = admin.firestore();
      await db.collection('urls').add({
        sendUrl: url
      });
 
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        slowMo: 0,
        args: [
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-web-security', // Disable web security to bypass CORS
          '--no-first-run',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--no-zygote',
          '--window-size=1280,720',
        ],
      });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
      );
    await page.goto(url);
    console.log('returning page')
  
    const title = await page.title();
    const price = await page.$eval('#priceAmount', (el: any) => el.innerText.trim());
    const image = await page.$eval('#landingImage', (el: any) => el.src);
    const thumbnail = await page.$eval('#landingImage', (el: any) => el.src.replace(/._.*_./, '.')); // replace the thumbnail image size with the full size image
    const description = await page.$eval('#productDescription p', (el: any) => el.innerText.trim());
  
    await db.collection('products').add({
      title,
      price,
      image,
      thumbnail,
      description
    });
  
    await browser.close();
  
    res.status(200).send('Scraped data and stored in Firestore');
      });
    
  });
```

The error is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.